# Reference Django Model Field from iterator in a for loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am attempting to create a model record using a `for` loop and cannot figure out how to reference the model field in a django `create()` function. I have mirrored response keys to the model fieldnames and want to loop through the response keys and assign the values in the model. Here is a simplified example.

```
r = requests.get(url)
r = r.json()

ModelOne.objects.create(
    for field in r:
        ModelOne.field = r[field]
)
```

I am trying to create the equivalent of

```
ModelOne.Objects.create(
    fieldone = r[fieldone]
    ,fieldtwo = r[fieldtwo]
)
```

Model:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    fieldone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fieldtwo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I do not think works is trying to use `.field` in `ModelOne.field` as the object attribute. It doesn't return any errors but does not save the record either.

I have also tried using raw sql with the django connection library but run into many other hurdles with that method.

Is there a way to do this using the QuerySet API or should I be looking into another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "*unpack*" the dictionary, with:

```
ModelOne.objects.create(**r)
```

if `r` might contain other fields than `fieldone` and `fieldtwo`, you will need to filter these out, so:

```
FIELDS = {'fieldone', 'fieldtwo'}
ModelOne.objects.create(**{k: v for k, v in r.items() if k in FIELDS})
```